# why is rendering turning form black

Tags: c#, winforms, rendering, buffering

I'm using an eye tracker to display eye movements on a form. The movements have been flickering a lot so I found out I can use BufferedGraphics which all works fine except when the eye movement starts it turns the form from the original colour to black. This is the code. Hopefully someone can help!

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var host = new Host();
    var gazeStream = host.Streams.CreateGazePointDataStream();
    gazeStream.GazePoint((x, y, ts) 
         => drawCircle(new PointF((float)x, (float)y)));
}

delegate void SetCallback(PointF point);

private void drawCircle(PointF point)
{
    float x = point.X;
    float y = point.Y;

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetCallback d = new SetCallback(drawCircle);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { point });
    }
    else
    {
        SolidBrush semiTransBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Coral);
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Aquamarine, 2);

        BufferedGraphicsContext currentContext;
        BufferedGraphics myBuffer;
        // Gets a reference to the current BufferedGraphicsContext
        currentContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
        // Creates a BufferedGraphics instance associated with Form1, and with 
        // dimensions the same size as the drawing surface of Form1.
        myBuffer = currentContext.Allocate(this.CreateGraphics(),this.DisplayRectangle);
        myBuffer.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, 100, 100);
        myBuffer.Graphics.FillEllipse(semiTransBrush, x, y, 100, 100);


        // Renders the contents of the buffer to the specified drawing surface.
        myBuffer.Render(this.CreateGraphics());

        myBuffer.Dispose();
    }
```

[image]

You can see in the image that the circle appears behind the controls which seems like the form is gone?

Comment: Try `myBuffer.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);` before drawing shapes - that is if you don't have anything else on the form

Comment: I have radio buttons and a label on the form. The controls still show. It looks almost like the background of the form has been removed rather than the colour just changing

Comment: Where is the code from the question? Show some more details about the method

Comment: Ok I added more information. But I'm not sure it makes a difference

Comment: Can anyone help?????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you allocate the buffer, it creates a compatible rendering surface with the graphics you provided. But it will not copy it or anything so if you just paint a single circle, the remaining parts remain black.

`BufferedGraphics` really can help you to avoid flickering in special cases (eg. when system double buffering must be disabled for some reason), but here this is an overkill.

So the key is just enabling double buffering and do every paint in the `Paint` event (or `OnPaint` method). In your code you do immediate paint, which always flickers. Instead, you should just invalidate the form and let the system do a regular repaint session, which can use double buffering if you wish.

Into the constructor:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

Then modify the click event:

```
private PointF lastGazePoint;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var host = new Host();
    var gazeStream = host.Streams.CreateGazePointDataStream();
    gazeStream.GazePoint((x, y, ts) => 
        {
            lastGazePoint = new PointF((float)x, (float)y);
            Invalidate();
        });
 }
```

The painting itself:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    DrawCircle(e.Graphics, lastGazePoint.X, lastGazePoint.Y);
}
```

And finally, modify `DrawCircle` to use the `Graphics` from `PaintEventArgs`:

```
private void DrawCircle(Graphics g, float x, float y)
{
    using (Brush semiTransBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Coral))
    {
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Aquamarine, 2))
        {
            g.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, 100, 100);
            g.FillEllipse(semiTransBrush, x, y, 100, 100);
        }        
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just need to figure out how to keep the circle moving if the user looks away from the screen and back to the screen again

Comment: Hi I am trying to use the same logic to play back the circle movements from an xml file. I am able to read the file and parse it to get the x and y but the circle will only draw once. I am using the same Draw circle and onPaint method but this time I have another method which retrieves the co ordinates                                                                                                     public void EyeMove(float x, float y)
        {
            point = new PointF(x, y);
        }

Comment: You should provide some details. Without source I can just suspect that you block the UI thread while you play the animation back and you will just see the last frame. The replay engine should not contain `Thread.Sleep` or similar thread-blocking techniques. Just post another question with details if it is not enough info.